# Перевод из 2-ной в 16-ную систему счисления

Tags: системы-счисления

Почему 1 разряду 16-ной системы счисления соответствует 4 разряда 2-ной системы счисления? Можете пожалуйста дать "математическое", если так можно сказать, обоснование этой вещи.

Comment: Потому что 2 в степени 4 равно 16 (какое странное совпадение)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте определимся с терминами. Что такое разряд относительно данного вопроса, или другими словами: "Что такое разряд в позиционной системе счисления?"

Согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4)

> это структурный элемент представления чисел в позиционных системах счисления.

Или грубо другими словами место элемента в числе

Например, для двоичной системы

| 4 разряд | 3 разряд | 2 разряд | 1 разряд |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/0 | 1/0 | 1/0 | 1/0 |

Для 16-ричной

| 4 разряд | 3 разряд | 2 разряд | 1 разряд |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0123456789ABCDEF | 0123456789ABCDEF | 0123456789ABCDEF | 0123456789ABCDEF |

Теперь зададимся вопросом сколько возможных вариантов (разрядов) 2-чной системы нам необходимо для представления одного 16-ричного разряда.

Немного комбинаторики. Нам нужно определить все возможные размещения с повторениями. Это называется *числом размещений (A) с повторениями из n элементов по k*, где
A - 16, число размещений
n - 2, количество элементов (1/0)
k - искомое количество разрядов

[image: form1]

или

[image: from2]

Преобразуем к логарифмическому виду.

[image: form3]

Логарифм 16 по основанию 2 можно представить как:

[image: form4]

=> k = 4

Давно не объяснял математику, надеюсь понятно